# How can I block Google Talk using SelfControl

Tags: gmail, google-talk, selfcontrol

I am experimenting with SelfControl. Great so far, but I am trying to figure out how to block the GChat/Google Talk app from within the gmail interface. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://support.google.com/chat/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=161980). If you add "chatenabled.mail.google.com" to your blacklist it will block just the GChat/Google Talk part of gmail, while still giving you access to the rest.